# Can't loop over backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone.js-collections

It seems that I can't loop through a backbone collection. I've seen this topic in several threads, but none of those solutions help.

```
render:function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        var that = this;


        console.log(this.projects.models);
        _.each(this.projects.models, function(model) { console.log(model); });

        return this;
    }
```

From this my console only shows Array[2]
I would expect to see each model as well.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 5):

To get your collection content as an array, use the method `toJSON` (e.g.: `collection.toJSON()`)

Next, to loop over your entire collection, use the `each` method on the collection instances!

```
collection.each(function( model ) {
    console.log(model)
});
```

If this don't show your full collection, then the problem is in how you add items inside your collection, not in the looping logic.